# markitup - live editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, markup, markitup

I've used the [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) library for the Rich text editor for my project.

However I need to make it in live editing mode which I mean, when I type a text then make a selection **Bold**, **Italic** or **Strike-out** it would render directly in the `textarea` without have to do a preview.

Something like with MS Word of Open Office Writer.

Checking with Firebug, markitup injects a `iframe` to do "preview" the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the markItUp home page:

> markItUp! is not a WYSIWYG editor, and it never will be.

What you are describing is a WYSIWYG editor. If you want to use one, I recommend something like: http://ckeditor.com/